# If i in string but partial is even ok python

Tags: python, string, if-statement, string-matching

I am sure this is simple but I can't see or possibly can't find a solution.

Suppose I have a string, for example `something--abcd--something` and I want to find `abcc` in the string. I want to allow for **one mismatch**, meaning that the output of the below code should be `True`.

```
my_string='something--abcd--something'
substring = 'abcc'

if substring in my_string:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

I know that the `substring` is not in `my_string` but then what I want is to allow for one mismatch then the output will be True.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: This isn't available as a builtin function in Python, but check out https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/fuzzy-string-python

Comment: If you want "fuzzy" matching, then you can't use `in`.

Comment: If the string you're searching for is short and can't contain characters that are used in regular expressions (such as / . * etc) then you could try `re.match(".bcd", my_string)` `a.cd` `ab.d` and `abc.` but using a fuzzy string matching library is a much better way to go.

Comment: @Samwise and @John Gordon - Unfortunately, I can not use "fuzzy" for what I want to perform. In a file, I have several strings with different lengths (substring is always in the same length) so setting a ```fuzz.ratio``` will not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly finer ways to do it, but one solution is to search for it with  regexes in which one of the characters is replaced by a dot (or '\w' if you want the character to be a letter and nothing else).

We use a generator to lazily generate the regexes by replacing one of the letters each time, then check if any of these regexes match:

```
import re
    
def with_one_dot(s):
    for i in range(len(s)):
        yield s[:i] + '.' + s[i+1:]

def match_all_but_one(string, target):
    return any(re.search(fuzzy_target, string) for fuzzy_target in with_one_dot(target))
    
def find_fuzzy(string, target):
    " Return the start index of the fuzzy match, -1 if not found"
    for fuzzy_target in with_one_dot(target):
        m = re.search(fuzzy_target, string)
        if m:
            return m.start()
    return -1

my_string = 'something--abcd--something'

print(match_all_but_one(my_string, 'abcc'))  # 1 difference
# True
print(find_fuzzy(my_string, 'abcc'))
# 11

print(match_all_but_one(my_string,'abbb'))  # 2 differences
# False
print(find_fuzzy(my_string, 'abbb'))
# -1
```

---

The `with_one_dot(s)` generator yields `s` with one letter replaced by a dot on each iteration:

```
for reg in with_one_dot('abcd'):
    print(reg)
```

outputs:

```
.bcd
a.cd
ab.d
abc.
```

Each of these strings is used as a regex and tested on `my_string`. The dot `.` in a regex means 'match anything', so it allows any symbol instead of the original letter.

`any` returns `True` immediately if any of theses regexes matches, False if none does.

Comment: Dear @Thierry thank you for your detailed answer. To wrap my brain around, would you please give a bit more details on the last lines of the two definitions? I am going to implement your code by looking for two substrings for a string.

Comment: Dear @Thierry could you please mention that how can I find the position of the "abcc" once the ```match_all_but_one``` is ```True```? Since it does not exist in the main string, it is difficult to use the ```find``` option in python.

Comment: I edited the answer. For your future questions, please make sure to make all of your requirements clear in the question when you post it, as some can make differences in the way one builds a solution!